# Reading and printing a matrix in c

Tags: c, matrix

I am trying to read and print a matrix in c,
but its not working properly.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
 int l=0;
 scanf("%d",&l);  
 int matrix[l-1][l-1];

 for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
 {
   for(int j=0;j<l;j++)
   {
     scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]);
   }
 }

printf("\n");
 for(int i=0;i<l;i++)
 {
   for(int j=0;j<l;j++)
   {
     printf("%d ",matrix[i][j]);
   }
   printf("\n");
 }

}
```

For input :
4
0 0 1 0
1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0
2 0 0 0
The program is showing output :
0 0 1 1
1 0 1 0
0 0 0 2
2 0 0 0

Comment: yep the only problem is the matrix declaration, should be `int matrix[l][l]`

Comment: yup,That was the problem.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int matrix[l-1][l-1];` is not correct. You need specify array size, and you want `l`. Then you get indexes `0...l-1`, but the size is `l`.

```
int matrix[l][l];
```

---

Also, even if it might not be a problem here, always check return value of `scanf`, and do something, even just abort, on error. So `scanf` line could be:

```
if(scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]) != 1) { 
    printf("Input parse error for matrix[%d][%d]\n", i, j); 
    return;
}
```

Read `scanf` documentation to understand its return value.

Answer (score 0):

Variable `int martix[l-1][l-1];` is declared but `matrix` is used in the program.
Check spelling of variable.

Comment: In that case it wouldn't even compile! I think he just wrote it wrong here